# Get the path between two items in array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, tree

I am trying to write a function to get the path between two items in array 
this array represent the connectivities between the items 
like a tree with no cycles for example:

```
 A=[1, 3, 0, 3, 2] 
 A[0]=1 // node 0 is connected to node 1
 A[1]=3 // node 1 is connected to node 3
 A[2]=0 //node 2 is connected to node 0
```

and so on,
So now this array generates a graph like this  `<4---2---0----1---3>`
And  this function should get the path between two given indecies in the array
if given 4 & 1 the output should be list of [2,0]

So I want to help how to start building the algorithm for this function?

I tried this code

```
    private List<int> getDirectlyConnectedNodes(int ind, int[] A)
        {

            List<int> directNeighbours = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((A[i] == ind || A[ind] == i) && ind != i)
                {
                    directNeighbours.Add(i);
                }
            }
            return directNeighbours;
        }
        private List<int> getPath(int ind1, int ind2, int[] A, List<int> path)
        {

            List<int> directNeighbours= getDirectlyConnectedNodes(ind1, A);


            foreach (int i in directNeighbours)
            { 
                path.Add(i);
                if (A[i] == ind2 || A[ind2] == i)
                {

                    return path; 
                }
                else
                {
                    getPath(i, ind2, A, path);  
                }

            }

            return path; 
        }
```

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Could you post a full example of what you wish. I think the example shows it a bit, but to clarify, you need to show the full array (with 4, 2).

Comment: 4 and 2 are the actual indcies

Comment: So A[3] = 3 is connected to itself? Why is the output 1? A[0] is connected to note 1, why is the output 4? This does not seem to make any sense to me.

Comment: It means that it is  the last node , but no node is connected to itself cuase it will genrate a cycle and the cycles arn't allowed becasuse this is a tree

Comment: This is a graph without cycles, so simple depth first search (ie the variant that doesn't check whether it has been here before) works. That is in fact what you're already doing, though there could be bugs.

Comment: Should I set a flag on the visited nodes ? or could you show me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find paths to root from both nodes, drop common part and join paths.

```
public static List<int> GetPath(int a,int b,int[] array) {
    Stack<int> stacka=GetPathToRoot(a,array);
    Stack<int> stackb=GetPathToRoot(b,array);
    int lastCommonNode=-1;
    while(stacka.Count>0&&stackb.Count>0&&stacka.Peek()==stackb.Peek()) {
        lastCommonNode=stacka.Pop();
        stackb.Pop();
    }
    List<int> list=new List<int>();
    while(stacka.Count>1) {
        list.Add(stacka.Pop());
    }
    list.Reverse();
    if(stacka.Count>0&&stackb.Count>0) {
        list.Add(lastCommonNode);
    }
    while(stackb.Count>1) {
        list.Add(stackb.Pop());
    }
    return list;
}
private static Stack<int> GetPathToRoot(int a,int[] array) {
    Stack<int> stack=new Stack<int>();
    for(;;) {
        stack.Push(a);
        if(array[a]==a) {
            break;
        }
        a=array[a];
    }
    return stack;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just start with the first index and keep going until you hit the second index? There doesn't seem to be any branching in your data structure, just a fixed path from one node to the next.

```
private IEnumerable<int> getPath(int ind1, int ind2, int[] A)
{    
    for (int ind = ind1; A[ind] != ind && A[ind] != ind2; ind = A[ind])
    {
        yield return A[ind];
    }
}
```

You might need to tweak it to cover the false positive you get if there is no path between the specified nodes, but when there is a path it should find it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clearify that there could be branching , not just a direct path